# Opening CSS file crashes Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

When I open a CSS file in any Cordova project using VS 2015, it crashes with:

> An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an
>   extension. You can get more information by examining the file
>   'C:\Users\a\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml'.

**Looking there shows:**

```
Editor or Editor Extension

System.ArgumentException: The value passed in must be an enum base or an underlying type for an enum, such as an Int32.
Parameter name: value
   at System.Enum.ToObject(Type enumType, Object value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.DialogPage.SetPropertyValue(PropertyDescriptor descriptor, Object automationObject, Object value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.DialogPage.LoadSettingFromStorage(PropertyDescriptor prop)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.DialogPage.LoadSettingsFromStorage()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.DialogPage.set_Site(ISite value)
   at System.ComponentModel.Container.Add(IComponent component, String name)
   at System.ComponentModel.Container.Add(IComponent component)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetDialogPage(Type dialogPageType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Html.Package.Package.CSS.CssPackage.GetAutomationObject(String name)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.GetAutomationObject(String propName, Object& auto)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Html.Package.Options.Common.WebSettingsStorageWithDialog.LoadFromStorage()
   at Microsoft.Web.Editor.Host.WebEditor.GetSettings(String contentTypeName)
   at Microsoft.CSS.Editor.Settings.CssSettings.get_Storage()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Html.Package.TaskList.CSS.CssErrorTaskProvider..ctor(ITextView textView, ITextBuffer textBuffer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Html.Package.TaskList.CSS.CssErrorTaskProvider.Attach(ITextView textView, ITextBuffer textBuffer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Html.Package.TaskList.CSS.ErrorTaskSetup.OnTextViewCreated(ITextView textView, ITextBuffer textBuffer)
   at Microsoft.Web.Editor.Controller.TextViewConnectionListener.OnTextViewGotAggregateFocus(ITextView textView, ITextBuffer textBuffer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Html.Package.Commands.CSS.VsCssTextViewConnectionListener.OnTextViewGotAggregateFocus(ITextView textView, ITextBuffer textBuffer)
   at Microsoft.Web.Editor.Controller.TextViewConnectionListener.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<OnTextViewConnected>b__0(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.RaiseEvent(Object sender, EventHandler eventHandlers)
```

I have tried restarting my computer, clearing the .VS folder and the .user file. The only extension I have installed that I am aware of is Ankhsvn.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with loading CSS files. The problem I had was, that my Visual Studio was synced with settings from the cloud. I had an extension previously installed, and this setting was synced to cloud. When I hadn't the extension any longer, VS still tried to sync the setting and failed.

I always got an error on opening CSS files and I wasn't able to open the Tools-Options-Text Editor-CSS-Advanced dialog.

For me, following helped:

1. Signed out from Visual Studio and closed all instances
2. Calling devenv /resetuserdata
3. Calling devenv /resetsettings
4. Not sure if needed, but then I deleted "C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio" folder (will be recreated on next start again)
5. Start Visual Studio and disable syncing of settings "Tools-Options-Environment-Accounts" and Untick "Synchronize settings"
6. After that, you can re-login to your VS account and everything should be fine.

Hope that helps you too.

Comment: Didn't work for me :-( and lost all  my IDE configurations

Answer (score 1):

I found a post on Visual Studio community site that worked for me.
In addition to the crash when editing css files, I noticed this symptom: going into menu 
Tools / Options / Text Editor / CSS section / Advanced displayed "An error occurred loading this property page"

The problem seems to be the Advanced settings are crashing it.

The fix is from chris at 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/309037/my-vs-2015-crash-when-i-work-on-css-file.html?childToView=467593#comment-467593

> Run regedit, find the HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \
>   VisualStudio \ 14.0 \ ApplicationPrivateSettings \ TextEditor \ CSS
>   branch and delete the Specific section in it.
>
> If you edit the Tools / Options / Text Editor / Css section / Advanced
>   it restores the registry entry which was deleted but this time there
>   is no error when opening a .css file.

I quit Visual Studio, deleted the registry entry above, started Visual Studio, went into the options menu just to set a couple options (and make it recreate the key, just in case it mattered), and I can open css files.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in Visual Studio 2015. Make sure that your Visual Studio is up to date. If the problem reproduces with the latest 2015 versions, you may want to report it to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html